# Filter nodes with respect to their outgoing links and to their neigbors

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a very simple graph built with the following query :

```
CREATE (a:root)-[:link{value:5}]->(b:leaf{value:10}),(a)-[:link{value:6}]->(c:leaf{value:11}),
(d:root)-[:link{value:2}]->(e:leaf{value:11}),(d)-[:link{value:7}]->(f:leaf{value:1})
```

and I want :
1) For each root node, extract its links with the maximum value.
That would be

```
(a)-[:link{value:6}]->(c:leaf{value:11})
(d)-[:link{value:7}]->(f:leaf{value:1})
```

2) Extract the node such that its leaf has the maximum value among those selected after step 1.
That would be

```
a
```

I can't figure how to retrieve this information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to order, collect, and take the first of the collection, since you can't use LIMIT here (as it applies to total rows, not results per row/root).

That gets you the relationship with the max value per root. You can get the end node of the relationship with the endNode() function, and once you've got that it's just a matter of ordering the results by the leaf value and taking the top row, and returning the root for that row.

```
MATCH (root:root)-[r:link]->(:leaf)
WITH root, r
ORDER BY r.value DESC
WITH root, head(collect(r)) as maxRel
WITH root, endNode(maxRel) as leaf
ORDER BY leaf.value DESC
LIMIT 1
RETURN root
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are amazing ! I wish I was that good at building queries... The result seems correct, I upvote your answer. 
I think I will need some time to fully understand your solution :)